# adding a playlist to windows 10 taskbar

Tags: windows-10, vlc-media-player, taskbar

Recently made the switch to windows 10 from xp and am running into an issue with the functionality of the new taskbar. I have a playlist file of radio streams saved and associated with VLC media player that would usually be a one-click operation from the taskbar. In Windows 10, for some reason when pinning this file to the taskbar it changes to a shortcut for the associated program.

When looking into this, I found one workaround that involved creating a shortcut of iexplore.exe that actually pointed to the intended file and it worked, but alas, I overhauled my computer since then and forget the method. I am almost there with a shortcut to iexplore.exe which has a target of:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" D:\backup\radio.xspf

And this works except for the extra step of selecting 'open' from the 'view downloads' window that appears. It must be some kind of switch or parameter that I am not remembering. Seems like something others would find useful, loading a playlist from the taskbar .. anyone have a lead to the site I found with this tip, or perhaps the missing parameter?

Comment: by the way, looking back at my google search history, the only related search I found was 'why duplicate icons taskbar windows 10' .. maybe this would help -- think I will work down the various links from there again _

Comment: there's also this, but it uses a third-party app: https://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/985014-guide-pin-programs-with-custom-launchers-to-taskbar/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps:

- First pin the `vlc.exe` in Windows Taskbar. This can be done in two ways.
  One is to drag and drop the shortcut from Start Menu to Taskbar. Another is to
  open VLC installation path, generally it is `C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC`.
  Right click on `vlc.exe` and choose 'Pin to taskbar'.
- Now open the folder where pinned taskbar shortcuts are saved. Generally, it is

```
C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar
```

- Then edit the VLC shortcut i.e. file name `VLC media player.lnk`. To do this,
  open Properties > Click on Shortcut tab > Edit the Target box with the command.
  For example, it will be VLC executable full path + Playlist file path.

```
C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe D:\backup\radio.xspf
```

[image: VLC-shortcut--properties]

Finally, log in and log out or restart Explorer process to affect the change.
The pinned VLC taskbar shortcut will open the playlist file directly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a shortcut to launch a certain program doing things, you need:

1) A shortcut that points to the program you want to use.

2) "Telling" the program shortcut what things should be done.

You mention a playlist file that you launch with VLC. So i don't understand why you're creating a shortcut for the Internet Explorer - doesn't seem to make sense for me.

Here is what i would do:

- Right-Click on an empty space on your desktop, select new > shortcut from the context menu
- Point this shortcut to the vlc.exe in the directory where you installed VLC
- Add a nice title, e. g. "Radio"
- Finish the shortcut creation

Right now, you only have a shortcut launching VLC, doing nothing else. Next, tell VLC what to do.

**Info, for a better understanding what you will do:**

What a program can do using such a launch method or not, is totally up to the developers. Some programs can be launched with lots of commands to execute, others can't be told to do anything.

What you do to "tell" a program a command is called *"using a command line argument"*. It's an old method of interacting with programs, that even worked with text-only operating systems. It's basically: `program.exe` will just launch the program, while `program.exe "do-this" "do-that"` launches the program with given instructions.

The VLC you are using can understand [a whole lot](https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help) of this commands - but you only need one specific: It should open your playlist file. Luckily, if the next best command after the .exe is a file, VLC does exactly this - it'll open it.

Get back to your shortcut now, right-click it and open it's properties. In the "Shortcut" tab there, you'll see the target you specified earlier - the full path to your vlc.exe. Click in that input field, press the [End] key to get to the right end of the vlc path there.

The vlc path itself should end with `.exe"` After that last quotes, press space and add your full file path there. Just to be safe, add the path in quotes, too - if your path contains any space character, they're needed.

So, now the target line of your shortcut should end with: `.exe" "D:\backup\radio.xspf"`.

Close the settings and double-click this shortcut now - VLC should launch and open the file you specified. If that's working now, you can pin this shortcut to your taskbar.

---

BTW:

1) Internet Explorer isn't a good browser choice. If you still use it for web surfing, think about a more safe one. Firefox will do great, Opera is fine - maybe even prefer the new Edge Browser from Microsoft, but avoid the IE.

2) *"Recently made the switch to windows 10 from xp"* - oh whow, congrats! You are aware that XP support ended years ago? It really was time to switch!